# Join two different MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my database and I would like to join them.

The purpose is to display all comments (friends and my own) on each article. I have managed to select and display my friends comments but not to join and display my own as well.

Table structures

friends:

```
id
follower
following
```

users

```
id
name
email
```

Query for friends so far:

```
SELECT following FROM friends WHERE follower='$follower'
```

Query for user:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$follower'
```

Comment: There is no `follower` column in `users` table.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to add mysql_real_escape_string to all variables that are sent to sql. So don't just leave follower='$follower'  but use follower = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($follower). "'. Other wise you might be attacked and SQL injected! Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) clause to join both your tables:

```
SELECT * FROM friends AS f INNER JOIN users AS u ON f.follower = u.id;
```

Then you can choose necessary rows that meet specified criteria. For example using [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM friends AS f INNER JOIN users AS u ON f.follower = u.id WHERE following = 1;
```